# How to give generic class from an object in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a XML serializer load method and it takes a generic class. But generic class is derived from another interfaces. I have been developing a plugin and it uses a common model.

```
//these are common for all
 public interface ICommonBaseSettings { }
 public interface IProductSpecific : ICommonBaseSettings { }

//this is for plugin specific
 public class GeneratorSettings : IProductSpecific { }
```

and I have a method:

```
public sealed partial class GeneratorPluginForm : PluginForm
{
     public override ICommonBaseSettings GetSettings(bool isGui)
     {
        return new GeneratorSettings();
     }
}
```

As you see GetSettings method returns GeneratorSettings.
Here is my generic class

```
public static class Serializer<T> where T : class 
{
    public static T Load(string path)
    {
        T serializableObject = LoadFromDocumentFormat(null, path, null);
        return serializableObject;
    }
}
```

If I call this like that, it works

```
var obj =  Serializer<GeneratorSettings>.Load("...");
```

but I have this code:

```
   PluginLoader loader = new PluginLoader();
   var pluginForm = loader.GetPluginForm("plugin dll path");
   var tmpSettings = pluginForm.GetSettings(false);
```

GetSettings method returns ICommonBaseSettings but actually it is the GeneratorSettings class.

For example this code does not work

```
 Serializer<Activator.CreateInstance(tmpSettings.GetType()>.Load("");
```

I want to give an object instead of "T"  into the Serializer

My question is that how can I call `Serializer<T>.Load("...");` method by using tmpSettings object.

I hope its clear.

Comment: No, it is not clear at all :) Show where is error, or what do you want (and for example it is not compiling)

Comment: How does the signature of `pluginForm.GetSettings(..)` look like? What's the ReturnType of that method? If I understand it correctly you try to call `Serializer<...>.Load(..)` with information contained in `tmpSettings`, right? Do you have any type information stored in `tmpSettings`?

Comment: @Verarind, i gave already GetSettings method in the code. It returns ICommonBaseSettings and tmpSettings is a ICommonBaseSettings but when I call at runtime then its GeneratorSettings. I just want to use the return type as generic T into Serializer<T>

Comment: @Piotr, I have an object that is ICommonBasesettings and I want to call Serializer<T>.Load(...) with using this object.

Comment: Try `((dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Serializer<>).MakeGenericType(tmpSettings.GetType()))).Load("...")` But it looks like you need a design-change. I don't understand why you've to create an instance of a generic class using reflection only for serialization purposes. It looks weired.

Comment: @Verarind, I got this exception An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Cannot create an abstract class.

Comment: Oh sorry. I tried to create an instance of a static class. Try `typeof(Serializer<>).MakeGenericType(tmpSettings.GetType()).GetMethod("Load", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Invoke(null, new object[] { <LoadArgHere> })` But it's still strange. You can try to replace `"Load"` with `nameof(Serializer<object>.Load)`. But keep in mind that this will call `Load` using reflection.

Comment: @Verarind thank you so much for your reply. yesterday i went home and could not see your message. I changed your code a bit and it worked for me. You can write it as the answer and i will accept it as answer. Here is my code changes = typeof(Serializer<>).MakeGenericType(instance.ProductSpecific.GetType())
                        .GetMethod("Load", new[] {typeof(string)})
                        .Invoke(null,
                            new string[]
                            {
                                @"xml path"
                            });

Comment: No I won't add it as answer. I don't care about the reputation. It looks too strange to me and I feel that there should be another solution for serialization but I can't imagine any because I don't have enough information about your surrounding source. I'm glad to hear that you've a working solution.